# Passing an array and something else to var args

Tags: java

I am calling a library method on a fluent API that takes a var args of Strings.  when I call it I always pass at least three strings and then a few more depending on circumstance.

Can have a final static array or something to capture the three Strings that are always passed?

Comment: Do u want to transform `ArrayList<String>` to `String[]`?

Comment: What API and method are you using?

Comment: Just wrap this method into your own that always pass these 3 values in addition to the other ones, received as argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
public class Overloaded {

  private static final String[] CONST_ARR = {"1", "2", "3"};

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Overloaded o = new Overloaded();

    o.withConstantStrings();

    String[] a = {"1", "2"};

    o.withAdditionalStrings(a);
  }

  public void withConstantStrings() {
    libraryVarArgsCode(CONST_ARR);
  }

  public void withAdditionalStrings(String... additional) {
    String[] join = new String[additional.length + CONST_ARR.length];

    System.arraycopy(CONST_ARR, 0, join, 0, CONST_ARR.length);
    System.arraycopy(additional, 0, join, CONST_ARR.length, additional.length);

    libraryVarArgsCode(join);
  }

  public void libraryVarArgsCode(String... args) {
    // librabry code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea:

```
static final String[] RESERVED = {"A", "B", "C"};

...

libMethod(Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(RESERVED), Stream.of("D")).toArray(String[]::new));
```